# Query results difference between EMR-Presto and Athena

Tags: amazon-emr, amazon-athena, presto, aws-glue

I have connected Glue catalog to Athena and an EMR instance (with presto installed). I tried running the same query on both but am getting different results. EMR is giving 0 rows but Athena is giving 43 rows. The query is pretty simple with a `left join`, `group by` and a `count distinct`. The query looks like this:

```
select
  t1.customer_id as id,
  t2.purchase_date as purchase_date,
  count(distinct t1.purchase_id) as item_count
from 
  table1 t1
left join
  table2 as t2
  on t2.purchase_id=t1.purchase_id
where 
  t1.item_type='ABC' 
  and t1.purchase_status='CONFIRMED' 
  and t1.region_id in ('A','B','C')
  and t2.status='Dispatched'
  and t2.purchase_date between date_add('day',-50,date('2018-09-13')) and date('2018-09-13')
  and t1.created_at between date_add('day',-60,date('2018-09-13')) and date('2018-09-13')
  and t1.updated_at between date_add('day',-60,date('2018-09-13')) and date('2018-09-13')
group by
  t1.customer_id,t2.purchase_date;
```

I tried some other queries but the results completely match. Not sure what is wrong with this query.

```
EMR Version: 5.17.0
Presto Version: 0.206
```

**EDIT:** I realised that the issue is in the first table itself. Presto-EMR is not able to find any rows in `table1` for some reason. Not sure why this would happen since both Presto-EMR and Athena are using the same Glue catalog. I also tried Hive in the same EMR instance and it is able to find rows in `table1`.

```
select * from table1 limit 10;
```

The above statement gives 10 rows with hive-sql but zero rows with presto-sql. I see the following exception in debug mode:

```
Query 20180917_075536_00023_4988g failed: com.facebook.presto.spi.type.TimestampType
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: com.facebook.presto.spi.type.TimestampType
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.type.AbstractType.writeSlice(AbstractType.java:135)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.reader.ParquetBinaryColumnReader.readValue(ParquetBinaryColumnReader.java:55)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.reader.ParquetPrimitiveColumnReader.lambda$readValues$1(ParquetPrimitiveColumnReader.java:184)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.reader.ParquetPrimitiveColumnReader.processValues(ParquetPrimitiveColumnReader.java:204)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.reader.ParquetPrimitiveColumnReader.readValues(ParquetPrimitiveColumnReader.java:183)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.reader.ParquetPrimitiveColumnReader.readPrimitive(ParquetPrimitiveColumnReader.java:171)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readPrimitive(ParquetReader.java:208)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readColumnChunk(ParquetReader.java:258)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readBlock(ParquetReader.java:241)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSource$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetPageSource.java:244)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSource$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetPageSource.java:222)
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.block.LazyBlock.assureLoaded(LazyBlock.java:262)
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.block.LazyBlock.getLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:253)
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.Page.getLoadedPage(Page.java:247)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.TableScanOperator.getOutput(TableScanOperator.java:245)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:373)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.lambda$processFor$8(Driver.java:282)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.tryWithLock(Driver.java:672)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processFor(Driver.java:276)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:973)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.executor.PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(PrioritizedSplitRunner.java:162)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.executor.TaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(TaskExecutor.java:477)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: As you isolated the problem to `table1`, would you be able to also simplify query that reproduces your problem? Did you try to look into `table1` format and particular files? Is there any mismatch between file schema and table schema? Are you able to isolate the problem to single file?

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I found an exception in debug mode for presto. Added details above. Not sure how to investigate individual files as there is a large number of parquet files in S3. I don't get why Hive-sql is able to give rows though.

Comment: Try `set session hive.parquet.use-column-names = true`.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I am seeing this error while executing the statement in presto cli. 

`Query 20180917_103930_00031_4988g failed: line 1:29: mismatched input '-'. Expecting: '.', '='`

Comment: `set session hive.parquet_use_column_names=true` worked.

Comment: Sorry, i copied config name instead of session property. Glad that you managed to find out that. I will turn this into an answer so that your question doesn't linger unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presto by default matches fields in Parquet with table schema based on position. If order of your fields varies (eg. has been written differently over the time), you need to enable matching by name. You can do this with `hive.properties`:

```
hive.parquet.use-column-names = true
```

or on the session level:

set session hive.parquet_use_column_names = true;

Here is a related issue: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/8911